# Is there missing a "who" in " the only person everyone can agree was actually present that day is Luke"?

Tags: grammar

In both events, the discrepancies between accounts are many and varied. Take Luke’s burn. Everyone who was there that day either saw someone who wasn’t there, or failed to see someone who was. Dad saw Luke, and Luke saw Dad. Luke saw me, but I did not see Dad and Dad did not see me. I saw Richard and Richard saw me, but Richard did not see Dad, and neither Dad nor Luke saw Richard. **What is one to make of such a carousel of contradiction?** After all the turning around and round, when the music finally stops, **the only person everyone can agree was actually present that day is Luke**.

Educated - Tara Westover

I don't know how to analyse this sentence, just wonder if it miss a "who"? Like below:

- the only person everyone can agree WHO was actually present that day is Luke

---

edited for "What is one to make of such a carousel of contradiction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is an omitted "who" (which English allows), but it's not where you put it.

> the only person **who* everyone can agree was actually present that day is Luke.

You could paraphrase it rather stiltedly as

> the only person such that everyone can agree that they were actually present is Luke.

Comment: wait, please I don't get it. "who everyone can agree was actually present that day.", there are 2 verbs in the clause? agree + was?

Comment: This is because English often allows us to omit complementisers. _Who everyone can agree [that they] were actually present on that day_. _Was_ is in the embedded _that_- clause (with omitted "that") introduced by _agree_. _They_ can be omitted because _who_ takes over its function, and _who_ usually takes _was_ unless there is a reason to expect it to be plural, whereas _they_ takes _were_ whether it is singular or plural.

Comment: I'd use ***that*** rather than ***who*** anyway *(...the only person **that** everyone can agree was actually present that day is Luke)* - and hopefully most learners would already know that "that" is ***always*** "optional" in such contexts.

Comment: oh, I read it wrong myself, sorry.